# Failed in async task

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am trying to implement the Async Task for cater the json function in android. The json function work totally fine in android 2.3.3. So now i need to implement it into android. 4.3 jelly bean platform. but it is not able to display any result as i expected. Something is wrong with the Async Task function. Please help....

```
public class Update extends Activity{

JSONArray jArray = null;
String result = null;
StringBuilder sb = null;
InputStream is = null;
String ct_name;
LinearLayout l;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Done layout",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //http post
            try{
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                 //Why to use 10.0.2.2
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/moodle/myFile.php");
                 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                 is = entity.getContent();
                 }catch(Exception e){
                     Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
                }
            //convert response to string 
            try{
                  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                   sb = new StringBuilder();
                   sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

                   String line="0";
                   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                  sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    result=sb.toString();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                          Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                    }



            try{
                  jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                  JSONObject json_data=null;

                    l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
                  for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                         json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                         ct_name=json_data.getString("name");//here "Name" is the column name in database

                     }

            }
                  catch(JSONException e1){
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Data Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  } catch (ParseException e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
             }
            return result;


            }



        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_1);
            txt.setText("Executed"); 
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "this is post",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ct_name,
                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         TextView textView = new TextView(null);
                         textView.setText(ct_name + " is out, please attempt it as soon as possible"+ "\n");
                         l.addView(textView);


        }
}
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "lol",
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
workable json code

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
JSONArray jArray = null;
String result = null;
StringBuilder sb = null;
InputStream is = null;
String ct_name;
LinearLayout l;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
//http post
try{
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

     //Why to use 10.0.2.2
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/moodle/myFile.php");
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     is = entity.getContent();
     }catch(Exception e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }
//convert response to string 
try{
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
       sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

       String line="0";
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                      sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
              Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }



try{
      jArray = new JSONArray(result);
      JSONObject json_data=null;

        l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
      for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
             json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
             ct_name=json_data.getString("name");//here "Name" is the column name in database
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ct_name,
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             TextView textView = new TextView(this);
             textView.setText(ct_name + " is out, please attempt it as soon as possible"+ "\n");
             l.addView(textView);
         }

}
      catch(JSONException e1){
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Data Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (ParseException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
 }


}
}
```

Comment: post your logcat here

Comment: check my updated answer...sure it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do something in `doInBackground(String... params)` which is not possible. When using Assync update anything in UI only in `onPreExecute` or `onPostExecute`. Inthis you are trying to toast and attaching the view which will end up crashing. if you really want to update the UI from background, even if its not a good appoch to sove the proble you can use `runOnUiThread(action)` . When ever using an Assync task keep this in mind. Updating UI is not possible from background.

Answer (score 0):

it is crashing because you are showing toast in doInBackGround() catch part. You cannot update UI from different thread.

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this :

```
            public class Update extends Activity {

        JSONArray jArray = null;
        String result = null;
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        String ct_name;
        LinearLayout l;
        String responseString;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Done layout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            new LongOperation().execute();
        }

        class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                // http post

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // Why to use 10.0.2.2
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://10.0.2.2/moodle/myFile.php");
                try {
                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    HttpEntity getResponseEntity = response.getEntity();
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(getResponseEntity);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
                return responseString;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String resultStr) {
                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseString);
                    JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("result");
                    l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        ct_name = json_data.getString("name");
                    }
                    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_1);
                    txt.setText("Executed");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "this is post",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ct_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    TextView textView = new TextView(null);
                    textView.setText(ct_name
                            + " is out, please attempt it as soon as possible"
                            + "\n");
                    l.addView(textView);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: 05-06 07:24:59.111: E/AndroidRuntime(2451): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 07:24:59.111: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
05-06 07:24:59.111: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
05-06 07:24:59.111: E/AndroidRuntime(2451):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)

it show up this error. i had google it, but no luck. I wonder what can i do...

Comment: what is your json array name... which store all json result

Comment: can you post your json result here?

Comment: the result i obtained is from the database. Yes it did show the record and answer when i compile it without the AsyncTask function. But when i try to add the asyncTask fucntion, it show error

Comment: I had add in the workable code, which is function well in 2.3.3 ginger bread. Once i add in the AsyncTask, and try run in 4.3 jelly bean. it stop working

Comment: after 2.3 you can not access the database directly ...you always use the asyncTask ...this link will help you http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

> but it is not able to display any result as i expected

You don't seem invoke the async task in the first place. Add the following to do so:

```
new LongOperation().execute();
```

Also add at least `e.printStackTrace()` to your `catch` blocks that don't have it to discover further problems.